# Unattended WinDbg script for breakpoints and delays

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I want to debug an application running on `Windows` by setting a breakpoint on a certain address, waiting till the breakpoint is hit, keeping the application paused for a certain period of time and then continuing. All of this should be done in an unattended fashion (e.g. a script).

To do this, I chose to use [`WinDbg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) since the scripting support seems promising.

Starting `WinDbg` and attaching to the process by process name can e.g. be done by invoking the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe" -pn my-executable.exe
```

Setting the breakpoint is done with the `bu` command:

```
bu 0x1337
```

Continuing works with the `g` command.

Delaying can be done with the `.sleep` command:

```
.sleep milliseconds
```

For writing `WinDbg` scripts [this](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/WCDA/WCDA-Sample-Chapter.pdf) PDF might be helpful.

How can I piece it all together? I didn't figure out how delaying after hitting a breakpoint can be done nor do I know how to perform all of those actions (including attaching) from the command line alone without loading up the `WinDbg` GUI at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what for you need to sleep

you can embed the script commands and pass it to and instance of windbg

with -c  switch  the command below lists the modules and quits the session

**windbg -c "lm;q" calc.exe**

you can put it inside a batfile and run the batfile 
like

```
cdb -c "bu %2 \".sleep 5000;g\";g" %1.exe
```

a gif showing how i broke on winmain slept for 5 seconds before allowing the exe to run below

[image]

Comment: I need the sleep to write into the process memory with another application in the meantime and then continue the execution to avoid concurrency/bad timing issues.